# FFMPEG Multiple outputs from BlackMagic input

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, one-to-many, outputstream, wowza

I'm currently needing help to achieve multiple outputs from one input.
Right now, the outputs are set like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -f decklink -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" -y -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 2300k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 1280x720 -bufsize 1000k -maxrate 3072k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_720p"
ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_720p" -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 900k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 854x480 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 1000k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_480p_hq"
ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_720p" -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 550k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 854x480 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 500k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_480p_lq"
ffmpeg -re -i "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_720p" -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 450k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 640x360 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 500k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_360p"
```

This uses quite a lot of processing power, and also generates unnecessary latency (since I have to stream to WOWZA first, then back to FFMPEG and then back to WOWZA).

And I want to optimize this.

I've been trying several methods, but I only managed to overflow the decklink buffer. How could I solve this?

Comment: With FFmpeg, you can simply list out each output on the same command line.

Answer (score 3):

As per @Brad's comment, you can select the source input and then create multiple outputs on a single command line, like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -f decklink -i "DeckLink Mini Recorder" -y -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 2300k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 1280x720 -bufsize 1000k -maxrate 3072k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_720p" \
    -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 900k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 854x480 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 1000k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_480p_hq" \
    -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 550k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 854x480 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 500k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_480p_lq" \
    -c:v h264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 114k -ar 44100 -async 1 -b:v 450k -g 5 -probesize 32 -framerate 30 -movflags +faststart -s 640x360 -bufsize 400k -maxrate 500k -shortest -f flv "rtmp://10.0.0.172:1935/Testing/live_360p"
```

(if you're running this on Windows then copy & paste the above into a single command - Windows command line doesn't support the backslash line-continuation feature).